# To Display two widgets in the same line

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter, linkedin-api

I have a Twitter and a LinkedIn Share Widget on a WordPress page. I am trying to display the two widgets in the same line but in vain.

[image: Here is a Screenshot]

This is the code for displaying the widgets.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a><script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script>
<script type="IN/Share" data-counter="top"></script>
```

I tried applying a CSS class to it

```
.share_icon{
white-space: nowarap;
}
```

But it still doesn't align horizontally. Kindly Help.

Comment: Do you mean in same line horizontally or vertically? This is how I got widgets when pasted you code in my site. http://imgur.com/a/4SsWr

Comment: Wrap this anchor tags in div and style it display:inline-block;@user3402248

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround both widgets in a span. spans are used for inline elements. here is a fiddle for it https://jsfiddle.net/wnsg3js0/

```
<span>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a><script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script><script type="IN/Share" data-counter="top"></script>
</span>
```

and a link to more on spans https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_span_tag.htm